# Certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

Tags: apache, ssl, xampp

I'm using XAMPP and started Apache but I cannot access my site over HTTPS.

I get the following error;

> [Wed Aug 20 08:05:33.208723 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 3784:tid 256] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
>       [Wed Aug 20 08:05:33.746774 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 3784:tid 256] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
>       [Wed Aug 20 08:05:33.825871 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3784:tid 256] AH00455: Apache/2.4.7 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1e PHP/5.5.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
>       [Wed Aug 20 08:05:33.825871 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3784:tid 256] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Nov 21 2013 20:13:01
>       [Wed Aug 20 08:05:33.825871 2014] [core:notice] [pid 3784:tid 256] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
>       [Wed Aug 20 08:05:33.830753 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3784:tid 256] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 4452
>       [Wed Aug 20 08:05:35.148052 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 4452:tid 268] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

Below is a snippet from my `httpd-ssl.conf` file:

```
# SSL Virtual Host Context
<VirtualHost _default_:443>

# General setup for the virtual host
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
ServerName www.example.com:443
ServerAdmin admin@example.com
ErrorLog "C:/xampp/apache/logs/error.log"
TransferLog "C:/xampp/apache/logs/access.log"

</VirtualHost>
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tested port 443 is open in your network? Check it through telnet. To me, that is only a warning not an error. `openssl x509 -in server.crt -noout -subject` should return the CN of the certificate

Answer (score 4):

> [Wed Aug 20 08:05:33.208723 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 3784:tid 256] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

This means there might be a server name of `foo.example.com` but the certificate is for `bar.example.com` only. In that situation, while Apache might try to serve such certificate, the browser s will not accept them when accessing `https://foo.example.com`, for instance.

Comment: Sorry but I dont understand exactly.

Comment: What I have to do to solve the problem?

Comment: You have to either fix the server name or to fix the certificate. Name of server must be included in the certificate.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich how to include the name in the certificate? when I generate the certificate it doesn't ask me the server name.

Answer (score 4):

server name used in Apache (httpd.conf) must be the same as the server name in apache (httpd-ssl.conf)  e.g. in Apache (httpd.conf) `ServerName localhost:8080` then in apache (httpd-ssl.conf) should be like this `ServerName www.example.com:8080`

Answer (score -5):

Try to install newer version not latest version

1. Backup all databases and code
2. Uninstall XAMPP
3. Install newer version

That should be fixed.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/

Answer (score -6):

In File "httpd-ssl.conf" setting :

**SSLEngine on (default)**

**change Off to SSLEngine setting**.

Comment: This is not even a remotely clear answer.