# XAMPP - RSA certificate and SSL error. How to configure httpd.conf and httpd-ssl.conf

Tags: apache, ssl, xampp

I installed `XAMPP` on an HP server, it has a valid IP address.

The XAMPP was working but a few days ago it suddenly stopped and stared reporting this error:

> [pid 4196:tid 404] AH00098: pid file E:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
>
> [pid 4196:tid 404] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

This is a snippet of `httpd.conf`:

```
ServerRoot "E:/xampp/apache"

ServerAdmin postmaster@localhost

ServerName localhost:88
```

This is a snippet of `httpd-ssl.conf` (enbabled lines):

```
Listen 443

SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5

SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin

SSLSessionCache "shmcb:E:/xampp/apache/logs/ssl_scache(512000)"
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300

<VirtualHost _default_:443>

# General setup for the virtual host
DocumentRoot "E:/xampp/htdocs"
ServerName www.example.com:443
ServerAdmin admin@example.com
ErrorLog "E:/xampp/apache/logs/error.log"
TransferLog "E:/xampp/apache/logs/access.log"

SSLEngine on

SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/server.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf/ssl.key/server.key"

<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>
<Directory "E:/xampp/apache/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>

CustomLog "E:/xampp/apache/logs/ssl_request.log" \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

</VirtualHost>
```

From what I have searched and proposed in [XAMPP - Apache has error with RSA certificate and SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25398331/xampp-apache-has-error-with-rsa-certificate-and-ssl)  I think the source of problem might be `ServerName` so I put the configuration but I really don't know how to configure it.

I tried the solution given in the above link, but it didn't work.

Comment: Neither of those messages are errors, just warnings. They won't stop the server from loading, and will occur only at startup. What's causing the unclean shutdown is probably the question you need answered. Might want to include logs from shutdown instead of startup; increase logging level if you don't see anything.

Comment: @miken32 thank you for your reply. the Apache is check as services.
What might be the cause of warning? some thing in the operating system or the problem is with XAMPP configuration?

Comment: It says right in the message what the problem is. There was an unclean shutdown, and your certificate doesn't match your server setup. But you should be looking at why there's an unclean shutdown, if you say it "suddenly stopped."

Comment: @miken32 I removed the `httpd.pid` file (which is a lock) and clicked on the start button, I saw the above error as well but first one was gone. I guess the problem is the second one.